# Chrome と Microsoft Edge の互換性(対応)について

Tags: html

以前のコードから不要な内容を削除しようと思い、見直しています。

Chromium版Microsoft Edge が公開されている、とのことですが、これによりベンダープレフィックスは不要になったのですか？
下記のような記述も不要ですか？

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: 要件次第であり、この質問文だけでは判断できない気がします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントにもある様に要件次第ですが、
IE9や8をサポートする場合には書くことをお勧めします。

IE11やMicrosoft Edgeのみをサポートする場合には削除しても問題ないと思います。
X-UA-Compatibleについての質問は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do)を参照してください。

IE11以降、ドキュメントモードは非推奨となっています。
詳細は[こちら](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/bg182625(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)を参照してください。